# localStorage check if new alert in all windows opened and set it

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a jquery with ajax to check new messages and show it to user in title.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = "0";

setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: '/js/alerts.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
       if( data.number > "0" ) {

    i = parseInt(i) + parseInt(data.number);

    localStorage.setItem("title_alert", +i);

    document.title = document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s+/, "");
    document.title='('+i+')' + " " + document.title;

       }
      },
    });

 }, 10000);

});
```

so if `data.number > 0` I change the title with the new number, the number of new messages.

The problem is I'd like to do the same in all opened pages. I think `localStorage.getItem` is a good choice. because I set it if there is a new alert... but my problem is with the logic to make it work in open window, without duplicate alerts and to know the right moment to clean them. any help?

Comment: You can also use workers. I think shared workers would work well in your case : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker

Comment: in case of using workers mind that they donot have access to the localStorage but indexDB

Comment: @Seblor thanks! how can I add it to my project? is it a .js file? do I need to download it?

Comment: @RickJoe You can just follow the example on the MDN page. Basically, the worker is a JS script running in a separate thread, written in a separate file, referenced by the JS on your page. But the doc is much better than my comment for explaning this :)